# python list comprehension result is strange

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I'm learning python syntax about list comprehension
my purpose is using list comprehension get `dic` keys and create new set data.
Here is my code.

```
    dic = {'hello': 2, 'hiaaaa': 1, 'goodmorning': 0}

    new_set = { len(name) for name in dic.keys() }

    print(new_set)
```

I expected the result is `{5, 6, 11}`not `{11, 5, 6}`.

When I add data to `dic` the result is always different.
Sometimes `dic` is ordered, sometimes `dic` is disordered.
So does python list comprehension have any special rules? Or is it a complex bug?

Comment: This is a set comprehension, not a list-comp. Sets are unordered collections.

Comment: If you need it ordered, could you just use a list?

Comment: is your result depend upon the value for the key ? like getting the result based on the value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) is unordered in Python. To preserve order, you can consider using an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) from the collections module.

[`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) objects didn't use to preserve order, but this behaviour is guaranteed after Python 3.7. OrderedDicts still have some advantages under the hood to be optimized for tracking insertion order, however.